# How to solve this relational division query?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have a table (`movies`) with two foreign keys, (`movie_id`, `genre_id`). Of course, both fields aren't unique.

How do I select the movies that have two or more specific genres?

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT movie_id 
FROM movies
WHERE genre_id = 1 AND genre_id = 2 AND genre_id = 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a `Relational Division` problem.

```
SELECT movie_id 
FROM   movies
WHERE  genre_id IN (1, 2, 3)   -- <<== list of genre_id
GROUP  BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3            -- <<== count of genre_id
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

If `genre_id` is not unique for every `movie_id`, a `DISTINCT` keyword is needed to filter unique ones.

```
SELECT movie_id 
FROM   movies
WHERE  genre_id IN (1, 2, 3)             -- <<== list of genre_id
GROUP  BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) = 3      -- <<== count of genre_id
```

Comment: Really thanks men, it worked fine. I wasn't figuring how to solve it

Comment: @JW웃 Could you explain more please about how the "having count(*) = 3" works? What if there were only 2 genre_ids? 5? Would you change the having count clause to = 2 or 5 respectively? I noticed also that if I don't have the having count clause the where in clause acts like a regular OR clause for each of the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I think the most general way is to put all the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
group by movie_id
having sum(case when genre_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when genre_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when genre_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each of the clauses in the `having` clause is counting the number of records that match each type of genre.